# XHR onreadystatechange callback function

Tags: javascript

I have scripted something, but now I dont know how to add a callback function to the onreadystatechange function of an xhr object.

Here is some code.

```
    function Trace (str){
      alert(str);
    }

    //login durchführen
    var Auth = {
        auth_url : "?evt=Login&mod=_do",
        loggedin : false
    };

    Auth.Init = function(){
        if(!this.loggedin){
            Loader.GetJSON(api.url+this.auth_url+"&username=****&password=*****", true, "Auth.Login");
        }
    }

    Auth.Login = function(object){
        Trace("Auth.Login");
        if(object.user_ok == 200){
            Trace("true!");
        }else{
            Trace("false");
        }
    };

    var Loader = {
      xhr : null
    }

    Loader.GetJSON = function(url, type, fnCallback){

        if (this.xhr != null) {
            try {
                this.xhr.destroy();
                this.xhr = null;
            } catch (e) {
                Trace("Fehler in Loader.Request : " + e);
            }
        }
        this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (this.xhr) {

            if (typeof this.xhr.overrideMimeType == "function") {
                this.xhr.overrideMimeType('application/json');
            }
            //********
            this.xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (Loader.xhr.readyState == 4 && Loader.xhr.status == 200) {
                    var data = api.ParseJSON(Loader.xhr.responseText);
                    if (typeof data == 'object') {
                        fnCallback (data);
                    }else {
                        Trace(":::: Error in Loader.GetJSON => invalid json");
                    }
                } else if (Loader.xhr.readyState == 4 && Loader.xhr.status != 200) {
                    Trace(":::: Loader.GetJSON Connection error");

                }
            };

            // ******************
            this.xhr.open("GET", url, type);
            this.xhr.send(null);
            // ******************

        } else {
            Trace(":::: Loader.Request Fatal Error");

        }
    };

Auth.Init();
```

But here I get an error: fnCallback is not a function

Comment: Remove the quotes from `Auth.Login` in `Loader.GetJSON(/*...*/, "Auth.Login")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `Auth.Login` is a string not a function. You would need to reference it using `window` for it to work:

Instead of `fnCallback(data)`

use `window[fnCallback](data)`